# my Housecarl disappeared

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the follower reya. I entered the lost knife hide out, turned around and immediately exited and she was gone. there was no fight so she didn't die. how do I find her

Comment: nothing was ever said she just vanished

Comment: If you are on PC finding your follower is trivial, follow the console commands in the linked question.  Otherwise, follow the suggestions in that question and if you still can't find her edit this question to explain what you have tried.